# Copying collections of sheets identified by name list to new workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy specific collections sheets within an excel workbook in separate workbooks. Not being a vba coder I have used and adapted code found here and other resource sites. I believe I am now very close having grasped the basic concepts but cannot figure out what i am doing wrong, triggering the below code causes the first new workbook to be created and the first sheet inserted but breaks at that point.

My code is below, additional relevant info - there is a sheet called 'List' which has a column of names. Each name on the list has 2 sheets which I am trying to copy 2 by 2 into new sheet of the same name. the sheets are labelled as the name and the name + H (e.g Bobdata & BobdataH)

```
Sub SheetCreate()
'
'Creates an individual workbook for each worksname in the list of names.
'

Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim sht As Object
Dim strSavePath As String
Dim sname As String
Dim relativePath As String
Dim ListOfNames As Range, LRow As Long, Cell As Range
With ThisWorkbook
Set ListSh = .Sheets("List")
End With

LRow = ListSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '--Get last row of list.
Set ListOfNames = ListSh.Range("A1:A" & LRow) '--Qualify list.

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False '--Turn off flicker.
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual '--Turn off calculations.
End With

Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook

For Each Cell In ListOfNames


sname = Cell.Value & ".xls"
relativePath = wbSource.Path & "\" & sname

Sheets(Cell.Value).Copy
Set wbDest = ActiveWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=relativePath, FileFormat:=xlExcel8
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

wbSource.Activate
Sheets(Cell.Value & "H").Copy after:=Workbooks(relativePath).Sheets(Cell.Value)
wbDest.Save
wbDest.Close False
Next Cell

MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the specific error you're getting / on what line?

Comment: Hi, it is  "subscript out of range", after it has created the first new workbook

Comment: Reading [mcve] might help improve your post - please [edit] your question with all the relevant information, don't leave important bits in the comments section ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change

```
Sheets(Cell.Value & "H").Copy after:=Workbooks(relativePath).Sheets(Cell.Value)
```

to

```
Sheets(Cell.Value & "H").Copy after:=wbDest.Sheets(Cell.Value)
```

Also it would be good idea to check if file already exists in selected location. For this you can use function:

```
Private Function findFile(ByVal sFindPath As String, Optional sFileType = ".xlsx") As Boolean
Dim obj_fso As Object: Set obj_fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

findFile = False
findFile = obj_fso.FileExists(sFindPath & "/" & sFileType)

Set obj_fso = Nothing

End Function
```

and change sFileType = ".xlsx" to "*" or other excet file type.

Comment: Thankyou, this worked and I have added the check in too. Many thanks, i will work on getting my basics better for future!

Answer (score 1):

This was the code i created to create a new workbook and then copy  sheet contents from existing one to the new one. Hope it helps.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
     On Error Resume Next
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     TryAgain:
     Flname = InputBox("Enter File Name :", "Creating New File...")
     MsgBox Len(Flname)
     If Flname <> "" Then
    Set NewWkbk = Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:J100").Copy
    NewWkbk.Sheets(1).Range("A1:J100").PasteSpecial
    Range("A1:J100").Select
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
    AddData
    Dim FirstRow As Long
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "Data Recorded At-" & Format(Now(), "dd-mmmm-yy-h:mm:ss")
    NewWkbk.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Flname
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        NewWkbk.Close
        MsgBox "File Name Not Valid" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Try Again."
        GoTo TryAgain
    End If
    MsgBox "Export Complete Close the Application."
    NewWkbk.Close
End If
```

End Sub